# JQuery border inside image

Tags: jquery, css

I have a image slider like this:

```
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="width:516px; position:relative;">
    <div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:516px;">
        <ul style="width: 999999px; position: relative; left: -516px;">
            <li style="width: 129px; float: left; list-style: none outside none; height:68px; margin-top:3px">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="p_5">
                    <img src="question_pliki/5.png" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
            <!--... many more <li> elements-->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want do is make a border on active image, and I have this JQuery script:

```
$('.bx-window ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li').css('border','none');
    $(this).css('border','5px solid #f28458');
});
```

It makes a border but outside the image, and ruins my layout.

Is it possible to make a border inside the image?

Comment: You are adding a border in the `li` not in the image.

Comment: [Is this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/f5eEt/)?

Comment: As a side-note: there is no need to travers back out from the clicked `li` to the parent, only to select all `li` elements. You can replace `$(this).parent().find('li').css('border','none');` with `$(this).siblings().css('border','none');` and it works too

Comment: try to put your image in background of your a tag. And after apply the border to the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `box-sizing` on the element to `border-box`.  This would allow the border to be inside.

```
.bx-window ul li {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```